# Simplest way to write Greek and English text in the long-term and for all OS

Tags: unicode, polyglossia, greek

I have written LaTeX documents with lots of greek text and also interspersed with English sentences some time ago. Including bibliography. I used babel and pdflatex for this.

Now I am trying to show someone the pleasures of LaTeX but I got bitten by the above, semmingly simple, task. Which is important to achieve.

Their OS is Windows. So I had them installed TexLive. My OS is Linux and OSX.

So, I am looking for the simplest, most hassle-free and the most long-lived solution for writing greek text interspersed with english and why not spanish and latin and french, in our beloved *TeX. The output should be PDF.

I am not interested to (I can't afford to) know the difference between xetex or luatex or the myriad other fanctions(?) of the tex clan. And if I don't then definetely neither any of those winword die-hard users I am trying to win over.

p.s. I searched with google and then specifically into this site for my problem. But I couldn't get a simple answer.

I eventually found/modified this which seems to work for me, any comments? :

```
    \documentclass[a4,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
    \setmainfont{GFS Didot}        
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    %\setmainlanguage[variant=poly]{greek}
    \setmainlanguage{greek}

    \begin{document}
    \latex αγάπη μου, είπε ο Περικλής σε γράμμα του στην Chloë

ahahaha
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Note `babel` also works with XeTeX and LuaTeX with minimal changes. You can reuse your previous code.

Comment: You don't need to know all the details of the differences between the various compilers (pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, context, ...), but one thing that you should know (and tell the potential users) is how to make your editor use one or the other. Then you can stick with an approach that works with one compiler, set that compiler as default, and start the "happy TeXing" as it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to write in multiple (non Latin) languages ​​is, in my opinion, to use LuaLaTeX. First of all, in this way you can use all the OpenType fonts available in TeX Live, without having to install them on the system (as you would with XeLaTeX).  Furthermore, some `microtype` features not available for XeLaTeX can be used with LuaLaTeX. I prefer to recommend a LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX solution because in this way you have maximum freedom in the choice of fonts. You can also write in Greek and other languages with LaTeX, in any font that contains the necessary glyphs, but in this case setting the font can also be very complicated.

Here is an example of an English document with parts in Greek, Russian and Spanish:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
  \newfontfamily{\greekfont}{GFS Bodoni}
  \newfontfamily{\russianfont}{Cochineal}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{english}
  \setotherlanguage{greek}
  \setotherlanguage{russian}
  \setotherlanguage{spanish}

\begin{document}

This is the main language, printed in Liberation Serif. 

\section*{GFS Bodoni Greek}
\textgreek{Πρῶτον εἰπεῖν περὶ τί καὶ τίνος ἐστὶν ἡ σκέψις, ὅτι περὶ ἀπόδειξιν καὶ ἐπιστήμης ἀποδεικτικῆς}.

\section*{Cochineal Russian}
\textrussian{Кому случалось из Болховского уезда перебираться в Жиздринский, того, вероятно, поражала резкая разница между породой людей в Орловской губернии и калужской породой}. 

\section*{Main font Spanish}
\begin{spanish}
  \begin{verse}
    ¿Qué es la vida? Un frenesí.\\
    ¿Qué es la vida? Una ilusión,\\
    una sombra, una ficción,\\
    y el mayor bien es pequeño;\\
    que toda la vida es sueño,\\
    y los sueños, sueños son.\\ 
  \end{verse}
\end{spanish}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your remark about installing fonts - in XeLaTeX you can also use OTF and TTF fonts that are not installed on the system, by putting the font file in the same folder as your document, or by putting it somewhere else and provide the full path, similar to the situation in LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Yes, but @biliako was looking to a suitable solution for those  "winword die-hard users I am trying to win over". I don't think "provide the full path" is a solution within the reach of such users. So, for those users I see two ways: 1) use the font of TeX Live or 2) install the font on the system. In both cases LuaLaTeX works fine without anything else.

Comment: To put the font in the working directory is not a general solution as it must be repeated for each new document. But you are right: in a way this could be considered a solution for "winword users"

Comment: Thanks for this. I will install fonts only via Tex Live and use these. just a clarification. are the contents of a LuaLatex document still Latex? Are there some additions which will render my document un-renderable by another *Latex? I am not talking in general, not about using foreign language (greek etc.). Secondly, I would like the friend to use Texworks editor installed with TexLive. That's still possible with LuaLatex right? (I think @Manjin made this clear and I will find where to set default) Thanks again all commenters.

Comment: (pdf)LaTeX is not compatible, for example, with `fontspec` which you generally load when using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Also there are other packages that only work with this formats (`lua-check-hyphen`, for example works only with LuaLaTeX). Anyway in most cases it is not difficult to change a LuaLaTeX preamble into a LaTeX one. But if the document body has many `fontspec`-specific commands and the preamble has Lua/Xe-specific packages or commands, it may not be so immediate.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, ```I prefer to recommend a LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX solution because in this way you have maximum freedom in the choice of fonts.``` point taken that's useful to know

Answer (score 2):

Since you have been using `babel`, here is a version of your document with it. As you can see, changes are minimal wrt `pdftex`. It works with `xelatex` and `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{GFS Didot}

\begin{document}

αγάπη μου, είπε ο Περικλής σε γράμμα του στην Chloë

ahahaha

\end{document}
```

As to the fonts, there is a list of recommended fonts available in TeXLive in [the `babel` site](https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/which-method-for-which-language.html#fonts)